# Abort php script

Tags: php, jquery

I successfully zip a folder through the following code:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:site+'/home/test',
        data:{item_name:item_name,ext:ext},
        success:function(result){}
    });
});

public function test(){
    $item_name=$this->input->post('item_name');
    $ext=$this->input->post('ext');
    shell_exec('cd zip_folder/; zip -r '.$item_name.'.'.$ext.' '. $item_name);
    echo '1';
}
```

But I have a problem when the folder is very large, like 1GB, it takes a lot to zip and I can't make more requests until the end of script. I want to give the possibility of being able to cancel the process using a cancel button. I already tried xhr.abort() but without success. Even when I press f5 the site stays in loading until the zip is complete. I would also like to know if pressing f5 is possible to cancel this script.

Comment: `data:item_name:item_name,ext:ext},` looks like a typo in here?

Comment: Check your php settings for ignore_user_abort. Sometimes it will ignore if the user aborts the script and continue to load it. Try putting ignore_user_abort(true); at the top of the zip method

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the code is working

Comment: ignore_user_abort(true) dont work, site continues loading by pressing f5 until zip is complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try get all the running process and identify the one zipping files and then kill the process. All with shell_exec.

Comment: This solution worked. I'm using other php function with shell_exec('killall -9 zip') to stop zip and in function test() added session_write_close() and now I dont have lock problems from server.